# using Switch with dropdown in jQuery, Not working

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, dropdown

I am trying to show and hide some html elements on selecting options in dropdown by using `switch` but not `if/else condition`. there is a fiddle. Please help me out.

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <select id='purpose'>
      <option value="0">Personal use</option>
      <option value="1">Business use</option>
      <option value="2">Passing on to a client</option>
      <option value="3">xyz</option>
      <option value="4">pqr</option>
    </select>

    <div class="test">

        <div id='business1'>Business Name 1<br/>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id='business2'>Business Name 2<br/>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id='business3'>Business Name 3<br/>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id='business4'>Business Name 4<br/>&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".test > div").hide();
switch($('#purpose option:selected').val){
    case '1': 
        $("#business1").toggle(this.value == '1');
        break;   
    case '2': 
        $("#business2").toggle(this.value == '2');
        break; 
    case '3': 
      $("#business3").toggle(this.value == '3');
      break; 
    case '4': 
      $("#business4").toggle(this.value == '4');
      break; 
    default:
    //
}
```

**[Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/gekt2wc9/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add change event of select box using

```
<select id='purpose' onchange="showdiv(this)">
```

And add this function inside script tag.

```
<script>
    $(".test > div").hide();
    function showdiv(ref){

        switch($(ref).val()){
            case '1':
                $("#business1").toggle();
                break;   
            case '2': 
                $("#business2").toggle();
                break; 
            case '3': 
              $("#business3").toggle();
              break; 
            case '4': 
              $("#business4").toggle();
              break; 
            default:
            //
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You aren't referencing the jQuery library in your jsFiddle link.  If you check the browser's debugging console, you'll see an error indicating that `$` is undefined.  In order to use jQuery you must first reference the jQuery library.
2. Your code wasn't wrapped in any sort of event handler.  Which means it executes *once* when the page loads, and that's all.  Since when the page loads none of the expected options are selected, nothing is shown.
3. You aren't executing the `.val()` function in your code (you forgot the parentheses).
4. You're referencing `this`, which would work in an event handler but in the context of your code it's just referencing the overall context and doesn't have a "value".

I've made corrections [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gekt2wc9/8/):

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function() { // wrapped in an event handler
  $(".test > div").hide();
  switch($('#purpose option:selected').val()){ // execute the .val() function
    case '1': 
      $("#business1").toggle(this.value == '1');
      break;   
    case '2': 
      $("#business2").toggle(this.value == '2');
      break; 
    case '3': 
      $("#business3").toggle(this.value == '3');
      break; 
    case '4': 
      $("#business4").toggle(this.value == '4');
      break; 
    default:
  }
});
```